# Requesting Explanation of code sample

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Following code segment, finds whether `test_command` has successfully executed or not; if it gave some error then it will store the error message in `err_msg`.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('%test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>NUL') DO (
set err_msg="%%~a"
)
```

The code sample is working correctly but i think i do not understand it completely. specifically this part  `%test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>NUL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discarding the `^` that are escape characters needed to pass the special characters to `for /f`, `2>&1` means take the handle to the standard output (stream 1), **duplicate it** and use the **copy** as the output for the standard error stream (stream 2), then `1>nul` sets the null device as the output for the standard stream.

So, it hides the data sent by the process to the standard output stream and takes the standard error stream and writes is to the original standard output stream.

This is used whenever `for /f` or a pipe needs to retrieve the information generated by a command but sent to the error stream. Both `for /f` and piped commands process only data in the standard output stream, so, to be able to read the error stream, the normal output is discarded (or not) and the errors are sent to the original output stream so it can be properly retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

`2^>^&1 1^>nul` is the same as (but escaped with `^` because it's in FOR /F called command) `2>&1 1>nul` which means  - print the output stream (**1** or where the commands print their normal messages) to nul (nothing)  and print the error stream(**2** or where commands print their error messages) to output stream.

As `FOR /F` catches only the output stream this forces the FOR /F command to process only the error stream.

Answer (score 2):

```
%test_command% 2^>^&1 1^>NUL
```

This command runs `%test_command%`.

`^` is an escape character (used so `>` is interpreted as a redirection (pipe character) instead of a normal character).

`1^>NUL`redirects stdout to `nul`

`2^>^&1` redirects errors message to stdout.

So stdout is thrown away and stderr is redirected to stdout.

Normal output is discarded and errors are now sent to normal output.

---

Source [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> Escape Character
>
> `^`  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text.
>
> When piping or redirecting any of these characters you should prefix
>   with the escape character: & \ < > ^ |
>
> e.g.  ^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^